Is checking for the default value of a char okay in Java?
I'm writing an implementation of a binary tree for my data structures class, where the only actual values are the leaves. These are always of char type, so my method of traversing the list was to iteratively break down the tree until a leaf (char was declared) is found. Because i can't check if a primitive is null, I used '\u0000' to check. This has worked for me, but the tutorial in Java documentation says "Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style." Is there any reason for this beyond preference, or could the output genuinely change depending on the runtime?
Unfortunately I cannot share any code, but this is less of a debugging question and more of a general Java question.
Many have added that this default char value can be an issue if it actually shows up as a value for a leaf, which is certainly something to consider but beyond this, is it unsafe?
Link to Java tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

It's a question of whether your data can ever assume that value. Or you could use a Character, or String.

Where does it say "relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style"?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

I wouldn't worry too much about programming recommendations in tutorials, even the Java Tutorial. Just ask yourself the question I posed above.

If I was designing a binary tree (of characters) I would design the tree invariants so that a node in the tree always holds a meaningful character.  Thus, a leaf node would be a node with a character, but with the left and right references set to null.  I'd use a different class to represent the base of the tree ... so that I could represent an empty tree.

But unless your requirements say that you can assume that U+0000 is not a "valid" character, you can't use the default value for char to represent anything other than itself.

You could also have a Boolean field to mark a leaf -- or, more usually, have a null pointer in the left or right child references instead of an explicit leaf node.

If you're operating on strings to get these chars then that's no longer valid, as int codepoints should be used. They can have a negative value which can never be a valid codepoint

BTW "javadoc" != "tutorial" -- usually the term "javadoc" is used for the API documentation (packages, classes, methods, ...) that is, the documentation that is done as /** ... */ comments in code

Use a class Node that does not have the char field at all and then a Leaf subclass that has it and always has a meaningful value in it.

Unlike all the suggestions to the contrary above, I use a single Node class for not only the nodes but the entire tree, and use @StephenC's left == right == null test to determine a leaf, and therefore whether the char field is valid. A leaf is a node is a tree.

The link seems to be somewhat specifically targeting when you declare a variable. Eg. if you have a field char c; you should assign it somewhere, even though it gets a default value of 0. If you plan on using it 0 as a special value then you should assign it. Of course it is a matter of taste.
